# How to find if table have table in it with given name

Tags: lua

How to find if table have other table in it with specified name?
Or how to conver table "var1" in table "t" into string? And use "for" loop with "if" to find it.

```
input = "var1"

local t = {
    var1 = {[..content..]},
    var2 = {[..content..]},
    var3 = {[..content..]},
};
```

Now how to find, if table "t" have table "var1"?

Comment: `local s=t["var1"][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on Mikes comment: indexing a table with a non existing key returns `nil`. See https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html

And since `nil` evaluates to `false` checking for existing keys is as simple as

```lua
if t["var1"] then
```

Or when the [identifier is valid](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html):

```lua
if t.var1 then
```

If you want to make sure `var1` is a table only:

```lua
if type(t.var1) == "table" then
```

See https://www.lua.org/pil/2.html